# A page documenting usage of various package managers

Tags: package-management

I'm looking for a reasonably up-to-date and comprehensive web page that documents differences in how to use different package managers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ArchLinux wiki provides a [Rosetta Stone](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta) for various package managers.

Answer (score 2):

I put together a cheatsheet for myself some time ago: http://nakedape.cc/wiki/PackageManagerCheatsheet

There are of course many more, but these are the ones I have to deal with most.